# Projector in Tensorboard python application

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, visualization, tensorboard

I have the following code and sample which is working fine and exactly I want it to:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
import sklearn.preprocessing
import datetime
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib.tensorboard.plugins import projector

valid_set_size_percentage = 3
test_set_size_percentage = 3
seq_len = 5 # choose sequence length
df = pd.read_csv("Test.csv", encoding = 'utf-16',sep=',',index_col = 0)
df.head()
def normalize_data(df):
    cols = list(df_stock.columns.values)
    min_max_scaler = sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
    df = pd.DataFrame(min_max_scaler.fit_transform(df.values))
    df.columns = cols
    return df
def load_data(stock, seq_len):
    data_raw = stock.as_matrix() # convert to numpy array
    data = []
    print(data_raw.shape)
    for index in range(len(data_raw) - seq_len): 
        data.append(data_raw[index: index + seq_len])
    data = np.array(data);
    valid_set_size = int(np.round(valid_set_size_percentage/100*data.shape[0]));  
    test_set_size = int(np.round(test_set_size_percentage/100*data.shape[0]));
    train_set_size = data.shape[0] - (valid_set_size + test_set_size);
    x_train = data[:train_set_size,:-1,:]
    y_train = data[:train_set_size,-1,:4]
    x_valid = data[train_set_size:train_set_size+valid_set_size,:-1,:]
    y_valid = data[train_set_size:train_set_size+valid_set_size,-1,:4]
    x_test = data[train_set_size+valid_set_size:,:-1,:]
    y_test = data[train_set_size+valid_set_size:,-1,:4]
    return [x_train, y_train, x_valid, y_valid, x_test, y_test]
df_stock = df.copy()
cols = list(df_stock.columns.values)
print('df_stock.columns.values = ', cols)
df_stock_norm = df_stock.copy()
df_stock_norm = normalize_data(df_stock_norm)
x_train, y_train, x_valid, y_valid, x_test, y_test = load_data(df_stock_norm, seq_len)
print(y_train[:2])
print('x_train.shape = ',x_train.shape)
print('y_train.shape = ', y_train.shape)
print('Inputs = ',x_train.shape[2])
print('Outputs = ', y_train.shape[1])
print('x_valid.shape = ',x_valid.shape)
print('y_valid.shape = ', y_valid.shape)
print('x_test.shape = ', x_test.shape)
print('y_test.shape = ',y_test.shape)
index_in_epoch = 0;
perm_array  = np.arange(x_train.shape[0])
np.random.shuffle(perm_array)
def get_next_batch(batch_size):
    global index_in_epoch, x_train, perm_array  
    if index_in_epoch > x_train.shape[0]:
        start = 0 # start next epoch
        index_in_epoch = 0#batch_size
    start = index_in_epoch
    index_in_epoch += batch_size       
    end = index_in_epoch
    return x_train[perm_array[start:end]], y_train[perm_array[start:end]]
n_steps = seq_len -1
n_inputs = x_train.shape[2]
n_neurons = 100
n_outputs = y_train.shape[-1]
n_layers = 2
learning_rate = 0.001
batch_size =10
n_epochs = 100
train_set_size = x_train.shape[0]
test_set_size = x_test.shape[0]

tf.reset_default_graph()

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_steps, n_inputs])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,n_outputs])


layers = [tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_units=n_neurons, 
                                 activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, use_peepholes = True)
         for layer in range(n_layers)]
multi_layer_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(layers)
rnn_outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(multi_layer_cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)
stacked_rnn_outputs = tf.reshape(rnn_outputs, [-1, n_neurons]) 
stacked_outputs = tf.layers.dense(stacked_rnn_outputs, n_outputs)

outputs = tf.reshape(stacked_outputs, [-1, n_steps, n_outputs])

outputs = outputs[:,n_steps-1,:] # keep only last output of sequence
                                           
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(outputs, y)) # loss function = mean squared error 

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate) 
training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess: 
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for iteration in range(int(n_epochs*train_set_size/batch_size)):
        x_batch, y_batch = get_next_batch(batch_size) # fetch the next training batch 
        
        sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={X: x_batch, y: y_batch}) 
    
        if iteration % int(1*train_set_size/batch_size) == 0:

            mse_train = loss.eval(feed_dict={X: x_train, y: y_train}) 
            mse_valid = loss.eval(feed_dict={X: x_valid, y: y_valid}) 
            mse_test = loss.eval(feed_dict={X: x_test, y: y_test})

            print('%.2f epochs: MSE train/valid/test = %.3f/%.3f/%.3f'%(
                iteration*batch_size/train_set_size, mse_train, mse_valid,mse_test))
            try:
                save_path = saver.save(sess, "modelfile\\model"+str(iteration)+".ckpt")
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                if not os.path.exists("modelfile\\"):
                    os.makedirs("modelfile\\")
               
                save_path = saver.save(sess, "modelfile\\model"+str(iteration)+".ckpt")
```

The following is my sample of what I am trying to execute:
[Same data Please click and see](https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/572fae56dcf9c5f8fa0144f64904ae0e)

I am willing to add the Projector of the Tensorboard to my code. But I could not understand how I can make it. I want to visualize the different inputs I am giving for my training. I am supplying the following columns and trying to predict the `ohlc` values.

```
'o', 'h', 'l', 'c', 'rel1', 'rel2', 'rel3', 'rel4', 'rel5', 'rel6', 'rel7', 'rel8'
```

I want to visualize the above columns in the projector to know how they are relating with each other to give me the output.
Please let me know what I can do to get what I am willing to.

**EDITED**:

I have tried something as follows but cannot see the projector tab:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_steps, n_inputs])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,n_outputs])

symbols = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, 1], name='stock_labels')
embed_matrix = tf.Variable(
                tf.random_uniform([1, n_inputs],0.0, 1.0),
                name="embed_matrix"
            )
stacked_symbols = tf.tile(symbols, [batch_size,n_steps], name='stacked_stock_labels')
stacked_embeds = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embed_matrix, stacked_symbols)
# stacked_embeds = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embed_matrix)

# After concat, inputs.shape = (batch_size, num_steps, input_size + embed_size)
inputs_with_embed = tf.concat([X, stacked_embeds], axis=2, name="inputs_with_embed")
embed_matrix_summ = tf.summary.histogram("embed_matrix", embed_matrix)
```

And edited the following lines in the session code:

```
merged_sum = tf.summary.merge_all()
    global_step = 0
        # Set up the logs folder
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('logs')
    writer.add_graph(sess.graph)
    projector_config = projector.ProjectorConfig()

            # You can add multiple embeddings. Here we add only one.
    added_embed = projector_config.embeddings.add()
    added_embed.tensor_name = embed_matrix.name
    # Link this tensor to its metadata file (e.g. labels).
    shutil.copyfile("logs\\metadata.tsv",
                    "logs\\metadata1.tsv")
    added_embed.metadata_path = "metadata.tsv"

    # The next line writes a projector_config.pbtxt in the LOG_DIR. TensorBoard will
    # read this file during startup.
    projector.visualize_embeddings(writer, projector_config)
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    if iteration % int(1*train_set_size/batch_size) == 0:
        global_step += 1
        mse_train = loss.eval(feed_dict={X: x_train, y: y_train}) 
        mse_valid = loss.eval(feed_dict={X: x_valid, y: y_valid}) 
        mse_test = loss.eval(feed_dict={X: x_test, y: y_test})
        _,train_merge = sess.run([outputs,merged_sum], feed_dict={X: x_train, y: y_train})
        writer.add_summary(train_merge, global_step=global_step)
```

Here is teh [metadata.tsv file](https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/67c282bfd493c8d6bfdc5eb7ca12d949)
Please let me know what I missed.

Comment: I believe the projector is used to watch how the samples/examples are represented in the condensed latent space. Your question asks on how different columns can be viewed. If you are looking to find which node has greater impact, then you must be chasing after gradients and not projector.

Comment: @solver149 May be your suggestion is good sir. But how I can implant it in my scenario. I am confused with it. And after your suggestion I am more confused. Please help me.